# Populate organized expanded list based on compact data in Excel

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, vba

I have a compact data, which should be extended in a larger sheet. Below are both charts. I have given first chart and I would like the second chart to be populated. Prefer formulas, but if it's VBA, that's fine as well. The second chart's "Dep" is already given. I have to populate Emp ID.

Please note I have [cross-posted this here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1019562-populate-expanded-list-based-compact-data.html).

```
Depa   | Emp ID                
------ | ------                                                                   
Mang   | 1002    
------ | ------   
Mang   | 1003   
------ | ------   
Mang   |   
------ | ------   
TV     |     
------ | ------   
TV     |123  
------ | ------  
TV     | 178  
------ | ------  
TV     |  
------ | ------  
TV     |  789  
------ | ------
```

```
Dep    | EMP ID   
------ | ------    
Mang   |  1002   
------ | ------  
Mang   | 1003   
------ | ------  
Mang   |   
------ | ------   
Mang   |     
------ | ------   
Mang   |    
------ | ------   
 TV    | 123   
------ | ------   
TV     | 178   
------ | ------   
TV     | 789   
------ | ------   
TV     |       
------ | ------   
TV     |       
------ | ------   
       |
```

Comment: I'm sorry but its completely unclear what your asking. Please edit your question and try to format it. Perhaps add a small screenshot and then try to describe in simple steps what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far. Which formulas have you tried already?

Comment: Thank you for owning up to the cross-posting. Would you edit your other post to link to here? That way, if any readers over there wish to answer, but you get an answer here, they can check that first.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for confusion. Basically, i'm trying to trransform the first (top) table into the second (bottom) one. The first chart is given. in the second chart, the column "Dep" is given. So far I've tried to use index/match, index/small/if. I think the second one has more chance to get it right, but Kth portion of the Small function which is shown with Row function brings the Kth portion with is out of range when the second chart is lot longer than the first chart/table. I hope i'm being a bit more clearer and once again my apologies for being vague.